# Function represented by power series

Tags: power-series

To what function does the function with power series , $ |x|<1$

$$F(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^6}{6}-\frac{x^8}{8}+\cdots$$ converge?

Comment: Do you have some sort of a table of "famous" power series at hand (exp, log, sin, etc.)? I think you could find this series in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-F(x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{(ix)^{2r}}{2r}$$

Now $\ln(1+y)+\ln(1-y)=-2\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{y^{2r}}{2r}$

Answer (score 4):

Differentiating, $F'(x) = x - x^3 + x^5 - x^7 + \cdots$. This is a geometric series, hence for $|x| < 1$

$$F'(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

Now integrate to find $F$.